# How to create Handwriting animation using Framer-Motion?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, css-animations, framer-motion

I am trying to resolve, how to create `handwriting animation` for my text using `Framer-Motion` and `React` (`Typescript` version).

The component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

const HandWritingAnimation = ( { text }: { text: string } )  => {

    return (
        <div>
            <motion.h2
                className="text-secondary font-nautigal md:text-6xl text-5xl"
                initial={{ opacity: 0, x: -20 }}  
                animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0 }}    
                transition={{ duration: 2 }}     
            >
                {text}
            </motion.h2>
        </div>
    );
};
```

export default HandWritingAnimation;